# Sorting by DateTime as a string

Tags: c#

I've got a recent date and time entry in a column. It's currently a string which works fine, however when sorting the column, it sorts by the first number (not as the actual chronological order).

Comment: Dates only act like dates when stored as dates.  Strings are not Dates

Comment: Why are you storing a date as a string in the first place?

Comment: @Plutonix: Well if you choose a reason format - `yyyy-MM-dd` for example - then dates sort fine, which is what this is about. I'd agree that *in general* it's better not to use strings to represent them, but for the purposes of sorting, it can be done.

Comment: While you can eventually make storing dates and times as strings work in specific cases (and break others) with enough work, you are far far better off storing dates as dates, times as times, and displaying them in the format appropriate for each case.

Comment: You are better off declaring and using as a DateTime. The only time it should be a string is when it is at the presentation layer (displayed)

Answer (score 1):

You're probably going to want the string in ISO 8601, which is sortable.

`DateTime`'s `ToString("o")` format overload will get you this format.

Example:

```
Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString("o")); // Prints 2018-03-22T12:01:53.4144051-07:00
```

Comment: Thanks for that, it works for sorting chronologically now. Would I be able to do it as dd-MM-yyyy and still sort it?

Comment: @JVDB If you sorted your list as `DateTime`s, you could output the string representation of the date however you want, but dd-MM-yyyy is not sortable.

Comment: I see, thanks! Also, without trying to over complicate it, is it easy to remove the 'T' and also get rid of the decimal place on the seconds with that standard format?

Comment: @JVDB You might find the [documentation on date formatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings) helpful if you want to customize the string representation of your dates.

Comment: @JVDB: Just use a custom date/time format that still respects ordering, e.g. `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss`, using the invariant culture. It would still be generally better not to treat date/time values as text if possible though.

Comment: @JonathonChase Thanks for the link, much appreciated.

Comment: @JonSkeet So I'll declare the time as DateTime in the View Model.
Then have something in the service like:
    Time = status.Time,.
Could I then add a format to it?

Comment: @JVDB: I really don't know what you mean by "in the service" - it sounds like you should really take a step back in terms of design. Ideally, keep values in their "natural" data type as far as possible, converting to text only when presenting it to users (or accepting it from users).

Comment: @JonSkeet So this is presenting to users in the form of a column front end. (that column needs to be able to be sorted by date by the users). I'm trying to fix a bug that was already written, hence the slight confusion here.

Comment: @JVDB: Discussing this via comments isn't really the way Stack Overflow was designed. It sounds like you need to update your question with a lot more detail, or potentially ask a *new* question. See https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/ for suggestions on writing good questions.